# Sorting a list of numbers first alphabetically and then numerically

Tags: c++, sorting, comparison

I have a requirement of sorting given numbers in alphabetical order first and then numerically ascending order.
For example I have these numbers

```
{"10", "1", "2", "20", "200", "3", "300", "30", "201", "21"}
```

I want this order

```
{"1", "10", "2", "20", "21", "200", "201", "3", "30", "300"}
```

I wrote the following comparison function to sort them.

```
bool AlphaNumericCompare(const string & str1, const string& str2 )
{
    int ind1 = 0, ind2 = 0;
    while ( ind1 < str1.size() && ind2 < str2.size() )
    {
        if( str1[ind1] < str2[ind2] )
            return true;
        else if( str1[ind1] > str2[ind2] )
            return false;
        ind1++;
        ind2++;
    }
    if( ind1 == str1.size() && ind2 == str2.size() )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if( ind1 == str1.size() )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this function gives me the following order

```
{"1", "10", "2", "20",  "200", "201", "21", "3", "30", "300"}
```

Where 200 and 201 are placed before 21.
Can anybody suggest how to change the above comparison function to get the desired sorting order?

Comment: Two calls to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with custom comparators should be all you need: The first to sort alphabetically, the second to sort numerically.

Comment: If we sort alphabetically first, Won't second numeric sort this original order? For example 200, 30 are placed in that order after sorting alphabetically. After numeric sorting won't this order be reversed?

Comment: I don't understand how the required output is sorted "in alphabetical order first and then numerically ascending order".

Comment: The task isn't clear. Do you want all numbers that start with the same digit to be together, and within those groups the values are ordered?

Comment: In the above example 200 should come before 30 according to alphabetic order, But 21 should should come before 200 according to numeric order even though it is reverse according to alphabetic order

Comment: @RaviChandra And so what ordering do you want?

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yes. I want that order. Sorry I could not express my problem clearly

Comment: After a little bit of searching, I think radix sort can be used to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

One call to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) should be enough, with a custom comparator function. Something like

```
std::sort(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection),
          [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
          {
              auto i1 = std::stoll(s1);
              auto i2 = std::stoll(s2);
              return (s1 < s2 && i1 < i2);
          });
```

Note that it's untested.

Comment: That's what they asked for, but I don't think it's what they want because it gives a different result.

Comment: Yes, It does not produce the required output.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the task correctly, you want the numbers to first be grouped by their first characters, and then sorted within those groups.

This appears to do the job:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) {
        return true;
    } else if (a[0] > b[0]) {
        return false;
    }
    return std::stoi(a) < std::stoi(b);
});
```

It first checks the first characters of the strings. If the first characters are the same, it performs numerical sorting.

Comment: Let me check this solution

Comment: @RaviChandra Check it on multiple inputs to make sure I've understood the problem correctly. It may just happen to be correct for the example you gave.

Comment: Yes I am testing on a large input. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not giving correct order for my large input. I am trying to prepare a small test case from the large which would fail.